# How to find to which random variable the sequence converges in probability. Is there almost everywhere convergence?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, almost-everywhere

Given a sequence of random variables $\{\xi_n\}$
\begin{equation*}
\xi_n(\omega) = 
 \begin{cases}
  -1 &\text{with probability $\frac{1}{2n}$}\\
   3 &\text{with probability $\frac{1}{3n}$}\\
   10 &\text{otherwise}
        \end{cases} 
\end{equation*}

1. I need to find to which random variable the sequence converges in probability.

$\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Similarly for $\frac{1}{3n}$:

$\frac{1}{3n} \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$\Rightarrow P(|\xi_n - \xi| \geq \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$

2. And define is there almost everywhere convergence or not.

Sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ converges almost everywhere to a random variable $\xi$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if $P(\{\omega|\xi_n(\omega) \rightarrow \xi(\omega) \}) \rightarrow 1$.

The answer is yes, because:

$\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$

and

$\frac{1}{3n} \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$\Rightarrow P(\{\omega|\xi_n(\omega) \rightarrow \xi(\omega) \}) \rightarrow 1$

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, You are right, the condition is wrong. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
$$E[\xi_n]=-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n}+10\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{3n}\bigg)=10-11\frac{1}{2n}-7\frac{1}{3n}\to 10$$
$$E[|\xi_n-E[\xi_n]|^2]=(-1-E[\xi_n])^2\frac{1}{2n}+(3-E[\xi_n])^2\frac{1}{3n}+(10-E[\xi_n])^2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{3n}\bigg)\to 0$$
We then employ Chebyscev's inequality and Minkowski's inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}P(|\xi_n-10|>\varepsilon)^{1/2}&\leq \varepsilon^{-1}E[|\xi_n-10|^2]^{1/2}\leq\\
&\leq \varepsilon^{-1}(E[|\xi_n-E[\xi_n]|^2]^{1/2}+|E[\xi_n]-10|)\to 0\end{aligned}$$